# In php, Prepare string and create XML/RSS Feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, urlencode, html-entities

I want to create my own RSS/XML feed.  I fetch data from the database to display, but keep getting invalid character errors.  If the string has an ampersand or other strange characters in it, the XML will be invalid.

I tried using urlencode and htmlentities, but these don't capture all possible characters which need to be escaped.  Does anyone know of a PHP function which will prepare a string for XML output?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601699/using-php-script-to-fill-in-xml/2602138#2602138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[htmlspecialchars](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php) should be enough. But don't forget to set the 3rd parameter (charset) to the character set matching the string charset.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
function html_special_chars($str)
{
     return preg_replace(array('/&/', '/"/'), array('&amp;', '&quot;'), $str);
}
```