# stripslashes and special characters?

Tags: xml, stripslashes

My xml feed file is using stripslashes, but I also want to remove special characters from som fields - how would I do that and where/what order would I add it?

```
$output .= "<address>".htmlentities(html_entity_decode(stripslashes($row->street_num)))." ".htmlentities(html_entity_decode(stripslashes($row->address2)))."</address>\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [In php, Prepare string and create XML/RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802695/in-php-prepare-string-and-create-xml-rss-feed/3250767)